# Grails Flot plugin Example server data not working

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I just included the Flot plugin and tried running the sample as mentioned in the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/flot). 
As per the documentation, the index page looks like this

```
class FlotController {

def index = {
  [data: [[0, 10], [4, 5], null, [6, 2.5], [12, 10]]]
}
}
```

When rendered in GSP, it

```
   var d4 = \u005b\u005b0\u002c 10\u005d\u002c \u005b4\u002c 5\u005d\u002c null\u002c \u005b6\u002c 2.5\u005d\u002c \u005b12\u002c 10\u005d\u005d;
```

what is the correct way to define data in the Controller? Thanks
The javascript is as shown below

```
        <g:javascript> 
var d1 = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) 
    d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];
    var d4 = ${raw(data)}; //line causing the problem
    var data = [d1, d2, d3, { label: "server data", data: d4}];
    var options = { lines: { show: true }, points: { show: true } };
    var d5 = []; 
    var series = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1; 
    for( var i = 0; i < series; i++) { 
        d5[i] = { label: "Series"+(i+1), data: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1 } 
    }
    var pieOptions = { series: { pie: { show: true } }, legend: { show: false } }; 
</g:javascript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT (with the good answer):**

For those who have the resources plugin, you need to replace :

```
<g:javascript></g:javascript>
```

by

```
<r:script>...</r:script>
```

And it works (with or without the function raw()

**Previous answer:**

In your GSP, you can use the raw() function.

More information here: [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#codecs)

But watch out:

"So what happens when you want to stop Grails from escaping some content? There are valid use cases for putting HTML into the database and rendering it as-is, as long as that content is **trusted**. In such cases, you can tell Grails that the content is safe as should be rendered raw, i.e. without any escaping:"

Comment: Still did not work for me. Within html it works (<p>${raw(data)}</p>) but when accessed from JS as var d4 = ${raw(data)}. Also tried unescape, json parse within js but no luck.

Comment: Just to be sure: this is what you have tried: <r:script>var d4 = ${ raw(data) }</r:script> ? And what do you mean by "did not work work me" ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the JS Snippet. Yes, I am using within the <g:javascript> tag and the original issue still remains with or without raw()

Comment: I tried a new project with Flot (it is an old plugin by the way). I have the resources plugin (grails 2.3.7), and I replaced <g:javascript>...</g:javascript> by <r:script>...</r:script>, and it works with or without raw(). Could you try this possibility ? If it works, I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you. I tried finding the difference between these 2 before accepting your answer. Could not, Would it be possible for you to share any link? Thanks again

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I just tried. If a master of Grails can see this comment, I hope he can give you an answer.